# Heroku: create webhook for app in team with role "member" via API

Tags: go, heroku

I need to create a webhook for an app in a team where my role is "member". When I send the POST request to create a webhook for the first time, I get the response with 403 (forbidden) status.
The request is:

```
POST https://api.heroku.com/apps/{{app-id}}/webhooks 
Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3 Authorization: 
Bearer {{token}} 
Content-Type: application/json
{"include": ["api:app"], "level": "sync", "url": "https://test.dev/webhooks"}
```

Response:

```
{ "id": "forbidden", "message": "You do not have access to webhooks for app-id" }
```

When I visit the app page in heroku and then try to send the same request again, I get a success response and the webhook is created.

So my question is, how do I create a new webhook at the first try? Has this happened to anyone else?